# Android: Content Adapter shouldn't be modified from UI Thread

Tags: android

Sometimes I receive this error on my Activity below, sometimes not:

```
The content of the adapter has changed
but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of
your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the
UI thread.
```

but I'm not sure where my mistake on my class below. Does anybody have idea?

```
public class FavoriteActivity extends SpeakSuperActivity {

        private final static String TAG = FavoriteActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private Button btn_filter_topic, btn_filter_rating, btn_filter_none;
        private TextView fav_filter_text;
        private static ListView listViewFavorites;
        private static TextView txtNoFavoritesYet;
        private List<Favorite> currentFavorites;
        private ArrayAdapter<Favorite> currentFavoritesArrayAdapter;

        // required for list loading piece by piece
        final int itemsPerLoading = Configuration.LOADED_ITEMS_ON_LIST_AT_ONCE;
        boolean loadingMore = false;
        private List<Long> idList;
        int currentDataLoaded;

        private static int oldBtnViewId = 0;

        // set the start value as same as the loading value
        int maximumDataLoadedYet = Configuration.LOADED_ITEMS_ON_LIST_AT_ONCE;

        // 0 = not sorted, 1 = sorted by topic and minimum number of stars
        private int caseSelection = 0;

        private static View progressView;

        private View footerView;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.favorites);
            Log.d(TAG, "FavoritesScreen onCreate()...");

            // indicator for waiting processes
            progressView = UIUtils.addBlockingProgressIndicatorBlack(this);

            // init Listview
            listViewFavorites = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fav_listview_favorites);

            // add the footer before adding the adapter, else the footer
            // will not load!
            footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listviewfooter, null, false);
            listViewFavorites.addFooterView(footerView);

            listViewFavorites = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fav_listview_favorites);

            fav_filter_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fav_filter_text);

            btn_filter_none = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fav_filter_none);
            btn_filter_topic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fav_filter_topic);
            btn_filter_rating = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fav_filter_rating);

            toggleButtonStates(R.id.btn_fav_filter_none);

            LoadDataTask ldTask = new LoadDataTask();
            ldTask.execute();

            // no favorites yet?
            txtNoFavoritesYet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fav_no_favorites_yet);

            updateUI();

        }

        /**
         * An asynchronous Task (doesn't block the UI Thread) for loading the Data in background.
         * 
         * @author Jonas Soukup
         */
        private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LoudmouthException> {

            private final String TAG = LoadDataTask.class.getName();

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                if (FavoriteProvider.getInstance().getNumOfFavorites() != 0)
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                listViewFavorites.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                fav_filter_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                btn_filter_none.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_filter_topic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_filter_rating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            protected LoudmouthException doInBackground(Void... params) {
                LoudmouthException exception = null;

                Log.d(TAG, "loading data..");
                switch (caseSelection) {
                case 0:
                    // Get FavoriteList without sorting
                    idList = FavoriteProvider.getInstance().getFavoritesByDate();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Get FavoriteList sorted by
                    // Topics + amount of stars
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

                    float minRating = prefs.getFloat(getResources().getString(R.string.rating_filter_star_amount), 0);

                    idList = FavoriteProvider.getInstance().getFavoritesByTopicAndMinRating(minRating);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "No Case with number: " + caseSelection);

                }

                // reset data loaded, so it loads till maximumDataLoadedYet on a
                // refresh of the list
                currentDataLoaded = 0;

                // reset List on Data change
                currentFavorites = new ArrayList<Favorite>();

                Log.d(TAG, "..loading data finished");

                return exception;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(LoudmouthException result) {

                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "LoadDataTask.onPostExecute()");
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (result != null) {
                        // Error ocurred during loading
                        android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener retryClickListener = new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                new LoadDataTask().execute();

                            }
                        };
                        UIUtils.showRetryCancelAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), result, retryClickListener, null);
                    } else {
                        // Everythings fine, data loaded

                        // showing & hiding

                        if (FavoriteProvider.getInstance().getNumOfFavorites() == 0) {

                            fav_filter_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_filter_none.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_filter_topic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_filter_rating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {

                            fav_filter_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btn_filter_none.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btn_filter_topic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btn_filter_rating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        if (idList.size() == 0) {
                            txtNoFavoritesYet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            listViewFavorites.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            txtNoFavoritesYet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            listViewFavorites.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    btn_filter_none.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            caseSelection = 0;
                                            FavoriteProvider.getInstance().setCurrentFavoriteListStateDirty(true);
                                            toggleButtonStates(v.getId());
                                            updateUI();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    btn_filter_topic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            caseSelection = 1;
                                            TopicFilterFavDialog tfFavDialog = new TopicFilterFavDialog(FavoriteActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.this, v
                                                    .getId());
                                            tfFavDialog.show();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    btn_filter_rating.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            caseSelection = 1;
                                            RatingFilterFavDialog ratDialog = new RatingFilterFavDialog(FavoriteActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.this, v
                                                    .getId());
                                            ratDialog.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    // init listview displaying with data loaded step by step
                    currentFavoritesArrayAdapter = new FavoriteArrayAdapter(FavoriteActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.this, R.layout.favorite_list_entry,
                            currentFavorites);
                    listViewFavorites.setAdapter(currentFavoritesArrayAdapter);
                    currentFavoritesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    // silent catch because activity could be closed meanwhile
                    Log.i(TAG, "silent exception catch in onPostExecute: " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update UI
         */
        public void updateUI() {
            LoadDataTask ldTask = new LoadDataTask();
            ldTask.execute();
            if (currentFavoritesArrayAdapter != null)
                currentFavoritesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            updateUI();
        }

        private class ListMoreItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LoudmouthException> {
            @Override
            protected LoudmouthException doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                LoudmouthException exception = null;

                loadingMore = true;

                // reset loading values if adapter was reseted
                if (currentFavoritesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0)
                    maximumDataLoadedYet = Configuration.LOADED_ITEMS_ON_LIST_AT_ONCE;

                // Get value of Configuration.LOADEDITEMSONLISTATONCE new listitems
                for (; currentDataLoaded < maximumDataLoadedYet && currentDataLoaded < idList.size(); currentDataLoaded++) {

                    // Fill the list with new information
                    currentFavorites.add(FavoriteProvider.getInstance().getFavorite(idList.get(currentDataLoaded)));
                }
                maximumDataLoadedYet += itemsPerLoading;

                // Done loading more.
                loadingMore = false;

                return exception;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(LoudmouthException result) {
                if (result == null) {
                    // Tell to the adapter that changes have been made, this will
                    // cause
                    // the list to refresh
                    currentFavoritesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // remove loading view when maximum data is reached
                    if (currentFavorites.size() == idList.size()) {
                        listViewFavorites.removeFooterView(footerView);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void toggleButtonStates(int viewId) {

            // set clicked button as selected
            if (viewId != 0) {
                switch (viewId) {
                case R.id.btn_fav_filter_none:
                    btn_filter_none.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filter_neuste_selected), null, null,
                            null);
                    btn_filter_none.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_fav_filter_topic:
                    btn_filter_topic.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filter_themen_selected), null, null,
                            null);
                    btn_filter_topic.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_fav_filter_rating:
                    btn_filter_rating.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filter_rating_selected), null, null,
                            null);
                    btn_filter_rating.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("TAG", "No View with id: " + viewId);
                }
            }

            // if previews Button exists and wasn't the same button set the old
            // one
            // to selected false
            if (oldBtnViewId != 0 && oldBtnViewId != viewId) {
                // set clicked button as not selected
                switch (oldBtnViewId) {
                case R.id.btn_fav_filter_none:
                    btn_filter_none.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filter_neuste), null, null, null);
                    btn_filter_none.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_grey));
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_fav_filter_topic:
                    btn_filter_topic.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filter_themen), null, null, null);
                    btn_filter_topic.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_grey));
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_fav_filter_rating:
                    btn_filter_rating.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filter_rating), null, null, null);
                    btn_filter_rating.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_grey));
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("TAG", "No View with id: " + viewId);
                }
            }
            oldBtnViewId = viewId;
        }

    }
```

Comment: runonuithread in onpostexecute is useless as onpostexecute runs on ui thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you modify currentFavorite in ListMoreItemsTasks, which is the underlying list that backs your adapter.

The modification is made in `doInBackground`, which is not the UI Thread.

I would recommend using publishProgress to receive the data to add on the UI Thread and add it to the adapter there (via the adapter's method, not the array, which you should probably not keep after having created the adapter)

## edit

Replace

```
private class ListMoreItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LoudmouthException> {
```

with

```
private class ListMoreItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Favorite, LoudmouthException> {
```

so progresses are Favorite elements, then

```
currentFavorites.add(FavoriteProvider.getInstance().getFavorite(idList.get(currentDataLoaded)));
```

with

```
publishProgress(FavoriteProvider.getInstance().getFavorite(idList.get(currentDataLoaded));
```

plus insert in the AsyncTask the onProgressUpdate :

```
onProgressUpdate(Favorite... values) {
    currentFavorites.add(values[0]);
    currentFavoritesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: could you post a correction of my code please? the part I need to change or remove? Thx